# Linking C++ libraries for Capn Pronto and Snappy

Tags: c++, homebrew, snappy, capnproto

I am trying to compile a c++ project, and it requires capn pronto and snappy. 
I have installed these using:

```
brew install capnp
brew install snappy
```

But I think I now need to link these libraries as I am getting the following error when I attempt to compile my project:

```
./base/columnfile.h:8:10: fatal error: 'kj/debug.h' file not found
```

kj is a library included in Capn Pronto. I have tried to link it using the command -lkj when I make, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you quote is a compile-time error, not a link-time error. The compiler is unable to find the KJ headers. To fix this, you need to pass `-I` flags to the compiler indicating where to search for headers. Usually, `-I/usr/local/include` is what you need, though it depends on where exactly the headers were installed. Or, if you have `pkg-config` installed, Cap'n Proto registers with it so you can do `pkg-config --cflags capnp` to determine what flags to pass (and `pgk-config --libs capnp` for linker flags).